# Pass parameter dynamically to the model and display the result in view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm passing dynamic parameters using foreach to the model to retrieve data. I'm trying to display the result in the view and getting few errors. Please suggest if there is any better approach for this scenario.

**Controller:**

```
$part_ids = $this->COC_model->getDesignParts($batch,$sr_no);
$parts_activities = [];
        foreach ($part_ids as $current_part_id) {
            $parts_activities['part_activities'] = ['part_id' => $current_part_id->id,
            'activities' =>$this->COC_model->getActivities($batch,$sr_no,$current_part_id->id),
            'row'=>$this->VDIR_model->get_batch_details($batch,$sr_no,$current_part_id->id)];
        }
$this->load->view('QC/COC',$parts_activities);
```

**Model:**

```
function getDesignParts($batch,$sr_no){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT 
        id,part_name,part_no 
        FROM 
            design
        WHERE 
            batch_id='$batch' AND
            sr_no='$sr_no'");
        return $query->result();            
    }
function getActivities($batch,$sr_no,$part_id){
        $query=$this->db->query("select activities,pi_activities.id as char_activity_id,specification_from,specification_to 
        from pi_activities 
        where batch='$batch' and sr_no='$sr_no' and part_id='$part_id'");
        return $query->result();             
    }  
function get_batch_details($batch,$sr_no,$part_id){
        $query=$this->db->query("select id,test_field 
        from test 
        where batch='$batch' and sr_no='$sr_no' and part_id='$part_id'");
        return $query->row();             
    }
```

**View:**

```
foreach ($part_activities as $getActivity): 
echo $getActivity['part_id'];
?>
<table class="table-bordered table-responsive  table">
<tr class="set-width1">                                            
<?php foreach ($getActivity['activities'] as $key => $activity) {?>
<td><?= $activity->activities;?></td>                                                    
<?php }?> 
</tr>
</table>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

**Errors:**

```
Message: Illegal string offset 'part_id'

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: why dont you join the table ?

Comment: I want to create multiple tables based on passed part_id. That;s the reason Ive added table inside the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are getting errors, but you should join the table not create a new table.
Correct code:

```
<table class="table-bordered table-responsive table">

  <tr class="set-width1">

    <?php foreach ($getActivity['activities'] as $key => $activity) { ?>

      <td><?php echo $activity->activities; ?></td>

    <?php } ?>
    
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

the date pushed to array is incorrect
it should be

```
 $part_ids = $this->COC_model->getDesignParts($batch,$sr_no);
$parts_activities = [];
        foreach ($part_ids as $current_part_id) {
            $parts_activities['part_activities'][] = ['part_id' => $current_part_id->id,
            'activities' =>$this->COC_model->getActivities($batch,$sr_no,$current_part_id->id)];
        }
$this->load->view('QC/COC',$parts_activities);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also please answer how to access the fields from the newly added 'row' in the foreach in the view? FYI, get_batch_details function returns return $query->row();